# GPIO and relay quesiton

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have a question about the YouTube video [Raspberry Pi Controls Relay](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LP9BKa-Adtk&feature=share). It's about controlling a [SainSmart 4-Channel 5V Relay Module](http://www.sainsmart.com/relay/4-channel-5v-relay-module-for-pic-arm-avr-dsp-arduino-msp430-ttl-logic.html). Is it driven directly off the 3.3V GPIO?

Comment: The schematic is on the product page: http://www.sainsmart.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/500x500/bbae6e2476339e906fab5b0d557fbc65/4/c/4channel-relay2.jpg

Comment: @Armandas - Your comment should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

That *might* work, but I wouldn't recommend it. You activate the relay by making the input on the module low, but I don't know if the RPi can sink the required 15~20 mA(*). But the problem is when the relay is off: the LED should drop the 5 V to an acceptable 3 V level, but since there's no current flowing the I/O pin may see close to the 5 V supply. Which it doesn't like.

I would recommend using an NPN transistor, with a 1 kΩ base resistor.

(*) *The main reason I'm reluctant towards the RPI is that there doesn't seem to be a real specification, other than the information gathered by third parties on the 'Net. Broadcom also doesn't seem to have a public datasheet of the SoC. I don't buy a product under those conditions.*